# React update object array with values from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, setstate

In my project I am using a textbox where user can paste a text with a set of questions and answers. I need to get the input split each line in an array and add an object to the setState array with index and the content of the line.

The array of object in setState is

```
const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState([{quin:0,content:'',examid:''}])
```

and after the text is pasted in the textbox

```
function changeText(e){
      let v = e.target.value;
      let ar = v.split('\n');
      let qu = [{quin:0,content:'',examid:''}];
      
      //console.log(ar)
      ar.forEach((element,index) => {
        
          qu.push([...qu,{quin:index,content:element,examid:'ABCD'}])            
        
      });

      setQuestion(qu);
      console.log('q: ' + JSON.stringify(question))
      
  }
```

Comment: What's not working?